# How to create Groups like in Whatsapp in a MySQL Database

Tags: mysql, database, many-to-many, usergroups

I am working on a program where I would like to like create a Group with Users which is then always there and saved in a MySQL Database. I just don't have any clue how to do this. I mean I could create a Table like:

```
GROUPID INT PRIMARY KEY
GROUPNAME TEXT
USER1ID INT
USER2ID INT
USER3ID INT
```

Then I would have to create A table which can take like lets say in this case 3 Users but isn't that a not performant and no possibility to dynamically make the group bigger. If I would like to make a friends list out of the Group then I also can't say that the User can have only 3 Friends. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: can you show me your data structure i want to develop something like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need 2 tables:

```
GROUPS - GroupId, GroupName
USERS - UserId, UserName, Password, GroupId
```

The GroupId in USERS links user entries to GROUPS. You can (should) also impose the link using a [foreign key](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html).

If a user can belong to more than one group, you will need a [many-to-many](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php) relationship. This is achieved with a 3rd table that looks like this:

```
GROUPS - GroupId, GroupName 
USERS - UserId, UserName, Password
USERS_GROUPS - UserId, GroupId
```

Comment: I already have a Users table but I am asking myself how I can dynamicly let a Group have as much Users as ist wants to have. Because in my example up there the USER1ID is a FOREIGN KEY but I can only have 3 Users in the Example. WHat I want to do is let the Group have as many members as wanted.

Comment: well... the USERS table is tied to the GROUPS table, not the other way arround. you should read a bit about 1-to-many relationships: http://www.databaseprimer.com/relationship_1tox.html

Comment: Yes I unterstand now Thank you. What a simple solution -.-

Comment: thinking about it, since a user can theoretically belong to more than one group, you should also look into many-to-many relationships (i'll also update my answer): http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php